# i have 40 bookmarks that i open daily is there a way to scrape just the updates and send via sms or email?

Tags: email, sms, screen-scraping, bookmarks, continuous

These bookmarks are search queries.

I know this is pretty broad, and new to this idea. I just don't feel paying a few hundred dollars a month is feasible or rational.

I have no problem getting hosting, etc.

Comment: Depends on the returned data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a useful free service called [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) (stands for *If This happens, Then do That*).

IFTTT works with channels, each channel can have trigger and/or actions. As an example, there are channel for Dropbox, email, SMS, RSS and many others. In IFTTT you can configure *receipes* like this: If the RSS Channel has new information, Then send the title or the content to email and/or SMS. You could use a receipe like this to do what you want.

If your bookmarks are not RSS feeds, then you'll probablly need to do some custom workaround (e.g.: create a php page in a free hosting that fetch your bookmarks information and returns it in the same format as RSS, and then use that page as an RSS Channel in IFTTT).

Comment: super late response but this was actually what I found to help me at the same time I wrote this question. I don't know why I didn't get an email telling me you answered. Thanks sergio